# How to avoid the execution of a sub query for some rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
// QandA
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+
| id |  title |                  content               | type | related |
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+
| 1  | title1 | content of question1                   | 0    | NULL    |
| 2  |        | content of first answer for question1  | 1    | 1       |
| 3  | title2 | content of question2                   | 0    | NULL    |
| 4  | title3 | content of question3                   | 0    | NULL    |
| 5  |        | content of second answer for question1 | 1    | 1       |
| 6  |        | content of first answer for question3  | 1    | 4       |
| 7  | title4 | content of question4                   | 0    | NULL    |
| 8  |        | content of first answer for question2  | 1    | 3       |
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+
-- type colum: it is 0 for questions and 1 for answers.
-- related column: it is NULL for questions and {the id of its own question} for answers.
```

Also I have these two other tables:

```
// interface_tags
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 1      |
| 1       | 5      |
| 3       | 4      |
| 4       | 1      |
| 4       | 2      |
| 4       | 5      |
| 7       | 2      |
+---------+--------+

// tags
+----+----------+
| id | tag_name |
+----+----------+
| 1  | PHP      |
| 2  | SQL      |
| 3  | MySQL    |
| 4  | CSS      |
| 5  | Java     |
| 6  | HTML     |
| 7  | JQuery   |
+----+----------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT id,
       title,
       content
       (SELECT i_t.tag_name
        FROM tags t
        JOIN interface_tags i_t
        ON t.id = i_t.tag_id
        WHERE i_t.post_id = :id1) tag
FROM QandA
WHERE id = :id2 OR related = :id3

-- Note: :id1, :id2 and :id3 are identical
```

---

As you see my query selects both the question (`id = :id2`) and all its own answers (`related = :id3`). There is a subquery which gets all tags for the question. But it will be executed per each row. So that subquery will be executed for both the question and answers. There is a lot of waste process, because answers don't have tags.

**What's my question?** How can I avoid of executing that subquery for answers? I mean I want to execute that subquery just for the question.

---

**EDIT:** Here is expected output:

```
-- :id = 1

// QandA
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+
| id |  title |                  content               |   tag      |
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+
| 1  | title1 | content of question1                   | PHP, JAVA  |
| 2  |        | content of first answer for question1  |            |
| 5  |        | content of second answer for question1 |            |
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Perhaps using `explain` will help what is actually going on rather than what you think is going on

Comment: Please don't tell me *"you have to use two separated tables for questions and answers"*.

Comment: Rather than just dumping your tables on us, it would have been helpful if you described the business problem and also showed us the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added expected result ...

Comment: You should really split the table into 2 - questions and answers

Comment: @juergend Look, no time to change the whole database structure. Just please tell me a approach to do that in the most efficient way. btw [SO does that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/421098) exactly as I do

Comment: Why don't you use two separate queries?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes two separated queries would be fine .. But what's wrong with one single query? Just I need to prevent of executing that subquery for answers.

Comment: @stack - Because two separate queries will be much simpler to write and read. Additionaly you will have your tags in an array. With one query you will first need to extract the tags from the question an parse the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need CASE here:

```
SELECT id,
       title,
       content,
       CASE
            WHEN type = 0 THEN      -- get tags only when post type is QUESTION
                (SELECT i_t.tag_name
                FROM tags t
                JOIN interface_tags i_t
                ON t.id = i_t.tag_id
                WHERE i_t.post_id = :id1)
            ELSE        -- else consider it an ANSWER and don't get tags
                NULL
        END tag
FROM QandA
WHERE id = :id2 OR related = :id3
```

Comment: I think using `type = 0` on the `WHERE` clause of that subquery will be much better than using `CASE`. Am I right?

Comment: After writing the long comment I realized you were asking something else. Well, still my answer is **NO** because if you put the condition in `WHERE` of subquery still it will hit the `tags` table and filter all the rows for an obviously `false` condition. `CASE` statement will prevent that useless searching in the table.

Comment: Just what do you mean *". . . useless searching in the table"* exactly?

Comment: Consider it like `if-else`, `if type = 0` search the table and get the tags `else` return NULL. Now suppose we remove this condition and say lets search tags for posts whatever the `type` is, for `questions` the query will return some result set but for `answer` there will be no results. So why would you execute the query when you know it will return nothing? That's why I called it useless searching.

Comment: The subselect can return multiple rows. You need to use `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name)` in the subselect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
SELECT q.id,
       q.title,
       q.content,
       GROUP_CONCAT(i_t.tag_name)       
FROM QandA q
LEFT JOIN interface_tags i_t
    ON q.id = i_t.post_id
LEFT JOIN tags t
    ON t.id = i_t.tag_id    
WHERE 
    q.id = :id2 OR q.related = :id3
GROUP BY
    q.id
```

This is possible solution which you wanted.

Comment: In your query, those two `LEFT JOIN` will be executed for all rows. Both the question and answers.

Comment: You can use an additional condition for the first LEFT JOIN: `q.type = 0`

Comment: Yes it will be more useful. So you can use more condition on join.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just execute two separate queries with a `UNION`?

```
SELECT id, title, content,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name)
        FROM tags t
        JOIN interface_tags i_t
        ON t.id = i_t.tag_id
        WHERE i_t.post_id = :id1) tag
FROM QandA WHERE id = :id2
UNION ALL
SELECT id, title, content, NULL
FROM QandA WHERE related = :id3
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd833/1)

Comment: This will be probably the fastest sollution. But you need to use `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name)` in your subselect.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel No this isn't the fastest solution .. This is just the cleanest. Actually I've created a benchmark and tested it. `WHERE id = :id2 OR related = :id3` uses an *index_merge* which is faster than `union`.

Comment: Then use `UNION ALL`. Also you should switch the (outer) WHERE conditions. You are executing the subselect for every answer.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Agreed, the `WHERE` conditions were the wrong way round and `UNION ALL` will be faster. I assumed the original subquery was correct, can you edit it with the required `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: Also fixed the missing `,` and wrong table alias for `tag_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CASE` expression, and add 1 more parameter so we have :id1 ... :id4 (all identical)

```
SELECT 
    id,
    title,
    content
    CASE WHEN id = :id1 
        THEN (SELECT i_t.tag_name
            FROM tags t
            JOIN interface_tags i_t
            ON t.id = i_t.tag_id
            WHERE i_t.post_id = :id2) 
    END tag
FROM 
    QandA
WHERE 
    id = :id3 OR related = :id4;
```

Comment: I think using `type = 0` on the `WHERE` clause of that subquery will be much better than using `CASE`. Am I right?